# Restore GRUB from Windows or from USB

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had a dual boot Win XP - Ubuntu. I deleted XP and I installed Win 7. Now, GRUB doesn't exist anymore. I made a live usb with ubuntu to repair grub, but usb doesn't boot(i used it in past to install and worked, but i formatted with Low Format Tool and USB doesn't boot anymore). So, I installed GRUB2Win and I created a Ubuntu menu entry, when i boot to ubuntu i receive: "Out of range".

Why this is happening? And how I can restore grub from windows or I it isn't possible, how I repair my USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinstall GRUB on Master hard drive - it'll automatically fix it and you will see that GRUB would also include both Windows and Ubuntu.  On your LIVE CD, do the same thing as if you were installing new system, but once you got past the hardware checking - cancel the process.  This, then will take you to menu and reinstalling GRUB will be in that list.  Pick that option, then voila!  Reboot after reinstalling GRUB.